# What does "Application Server" in Windows Server 2008 mean?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

When seeing the Windows Server 2008 R2 edition comparision by Role, i noticed that there is an entry for Application Server separate from that of IIS. 
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx

What is confusing me is that for Web edition, "Application Server" is not ticked but IIS is ticked.

Isnt IIS both the web server and the application server in Windows? 
And if so, if i take the web edition, can i not host my business components (WCF services)on it because it is not an "Application Server" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Application Server role provides the .NET framework 3.0 and associated services.

Please see [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754024%28WS.10%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: thanks - that was exactly what i was looking for. Which makes me realise that googling might have been more suitable. Thanks for the reply though. That was perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like WCF on Windows Server 2008 Web Edition is a no-go, though I'm having the usual trouble I have w/ Microsoft re: finding a concise statement of fact.

I would suspect that the lack of message queueing functionality in the Web Server Edition is probably the reason for the lack of support (see [Operating System Resources Required by WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702743(v=VS.90).aspx) for background).

Comment: I had the same problem about it not being too clear in different places. But you are right about the fact that my using WCF means web edition is a no-go for me. Its a bit sad though coz now my clients will have to purchase CAL's which otherwise wouldnt be needed with the web edition - if i understood the licensing part correctly.